# ASM change methodref

Tags: java

I'm changing a method so that instead of calling X.interfaceMethod() calls Xhelper.staticMethod(X);
The output is roughly:

```
public static java.lang.String str(batik.TwinMeck$Uberchild);
descriptor: (Lbatik/TwinMeck$Uberchild;)Ljava/lang/String;
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0       
     1: invokestatic  #19                 // InterfaceMethod batik/TwinMeck$Child3helper.str:(Lbatik/TwinMeck$Child3;)Ljava/lang/String;
     4: areturn       
  LineNumberTable:
    line 34: 0
```

But the bytecode verification fails on

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    batik/TwinMeck$Uberchildhelper.str(Lbatik/TwinMeck$Uberchild;)Ljava/lang/String; @1: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 19 is invalid
```

Where constant pool index 19 ==

```
#19 = InterfaceMethodref #16.#18        //  batik/TwinMeck$Child3helper.str(Lbatik/TwinMeck$Child3;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

But 19 should not be a InterfaceMethodRef, rather a MethodRef. How can i tell ASM5 to please make the entry a MethodRef instead of a InterfaceMethodRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misstake of mine, of course

```
class InterfaceToHelperRewriter(mv: MethodVisitor) extends MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, mv) {
  override def visitMethodInsn(opcode: Int, owner: String, name: String, desc: String, itf: Boolean) = opcode match {
    case INVOKESPECIAL if owner.getInternalClass.isInterface =>
      println(s"Messing up $owner $name $desc")
      super.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, owner + "helper", name, desc.addParam(owner), false)  // <-------- i used itf instead of false, now it generates a MethodRef and not a InterfaceMethodRef
    case _ =>
      super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf)
  }
}
```